# ggplot grouped stack bar to show proportion

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the following format:

```
Year    Group    Completed    Sum
2019      A         201        502
2019      B         454        521
2019      C         302        488
2020      A         382        400
2020      B         234        509
2020      C         354        432
```

I am trying to created a grouped stack bar chart that displays the years in facets and then each group. I want the height of the bars to be the value of Sum and then the stack in the bar to go up to the value of completed.

I currently have:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Sum, fill = Completed)) +
    geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap( ~ Year)
```

This is giving me everything I want except instead of completed being a stack on each bar it is coloring the bar based on the value of completed. How can I change it so that completed becomes a stack within each bar that goes up to the height of completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a bit of work on df before plotting it...

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(Incomplete = Sum - Completed) %>%     #calculate Incomplete
  pivot_longer(c(Completed, Incomplete)) %>%        #convert to long format
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = value, fill = name)) +  #fill is Complete or Incomplete
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap( ~ Year)
```

[image]

To put `Completed` on the bottom of each bar, replace `fill = name` with `fill = fct_rev(name)` in the `aes()` statement. (Thanks to @utubun for pointing this out).

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to do it as @Andrew Gustar did (however I would expect *Completed* to start from the bottom). Just consider it as an alternative workaround, demonstrating how you can achieve the same using `ggplot::geom_tile()`

#### Code

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  rename_all(tolower) %>%
  mutate(
    y_com = completed / 2,
    y_sum = (completed + sum) / 2
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(y_com, y_sum), values_to = 'y') %>%
  mutate(
    height     = ifelse(name == 'y_com', completed,  sum - completed),
    width      = .75,
    label      = ifelse(name == 'y_com', completed, sum),
    name       = gsub('y_', '', name),
    completed  = NULL,
    sum        = NULL,
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = y, height = height, width = width, fill = name, label = label)) +
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(y = label), vjust = -.25, colour = 'gray75') +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 'Blues', direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  labs(
    title   = 'ggplot grouped stack bar to show proportion',
    caption = 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/67607061/1861328',
    x       = 'Group',
    y       = 'Value'
  ) +
  ggthemes::theme_few()
```

[image]

#### Data

```r
dat <- structure(
  list(
    Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L),
    Group = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
    Completed = c(201L, 454L, 302L, 382L, 234L, 354L),
    Sum = c(502L, 521L, 488L, 400L, 509L, 432L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-6L)
)
```